# Evaluate $ \int \frac{e^x}{\left({1+\cos(x)}\right)} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

**Background**: I was in the process of solving some interesting integrals from this site, only to find out I needed a lot more practice before becoming familiar with special functions.

So while doing some problems, I encountered some difficulty with one particular integral; I happened to incorrectly copy it onto a notebook. But I'm curious to know as to how exactly I can evaluate this particular integral.

Essentially, I need help in evaluating the following integral :-

---

$$ \int \frac{e^x}{\left({1+\cos(x)}\right)} dx$$

**Question: How exactly can I evaluate this integral?**

*Both solutions as well as hints would be greatly appreciated.*

---

Note: Original problem had $\cosh(x)$ instead of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: It doesn't look integrable by hand: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2F%281%2Bcos+x%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand does not possess an elementary antiderivative. This can be shown using either [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). However, doing so requires advanced knowledge 
 of abstract algebra. Alternately, expand $~\dfrac1{1+\cos x}~$ into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), then switch the 
 order of summation and integration to obtain an infinite series, which you might rewrite in 
 terms of [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: See also [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Comment: By elementary you mean an antiderivative without special functions right? Because the answer seems to possess the hypergeometric function.

Comment: @Kugelblitz: Yes, you can use either hypergeometric series, or [incomplete beta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

Answer (score 1):

If you have $\cosh x$ instead of $\cos x$.:$$\int \frac{e^x}{\left({1+\cosh x}\right)} dx=\int \frac{2e^{2x}}{\left({e^{2x}+2e^x+1}\right)} dx=\int\dfrac{2e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}d(e^x)$$
 For your question we can use the fact that, $$\cos x=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=\dfrac{e^{2ix}+1}{2e^{ix}}.$$ Then it becomes
$$\int \frac{e^x}{\left({1+\cos x}\right)} dx=\int \frac{2e^{(1+i)x}}{\left({e^{2ix}+2e^{ix}+1}\right)} dx=\int\dfrac{2e^{(1+i)x}}{(1+e^{ix})^2}dx$$ Which does not seems like integrable by elementary methods as  Surb commented.

Comment: Alright. Are there 'non-elementary' methods to evaluate this?

Comment: I am not familiar with [Hypergeometric Function.](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHypergeometric_function&ei=msPtVPqPEaXCmAXJhYHwCQ&usg=AFQjCNGP_kk8FbzWNk5Z1Cy2bqqUBlUhdw&bvm=bv.86956481,d.dGY) But most of these type of integrals can solve using that function. There are many professional mathematicians in this site who know about that function than me.

Comment: Well, I thank you so much for trying; I'll try doing something with the simplification you've made. Let's wait for others to try and answer... As you said, some use ingenious methods to integrate in the website; nevertheless I've given you an upvote, for your answer is useful. Interesting question don't you think? :)